# SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: java, hibernate

**WHEN I GAVE MY LOGIN id,pwd ...**

`http://localhost:8080/project_name`.  the error is 
The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.**
I'm using jboss4.2.3 and pls let me know where the problem is...?**

HTTP Status 500 -

---

type Exception report

**message**

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet action threw exception
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
...
```

**root cause**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    com.fanniemae.rbc.rollup.ui.RollupActionServlet.init(RollupActionServlet.java:26)
...
```

**root cause**

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
```

**root cause**

```
org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection); - nested throwable: (org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection))
    org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:95)
    org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:69)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:423)
...
```

**root cause**

```
org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection)
...
```

**root cause**

```
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:441)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:172)
    org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:619)
    org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:264)
    org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool$BasePool.getConnection(JBossManagedConnectionPool.java:575)
    org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:347)
    org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManager.java:330)
    org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:402)
    org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:849)
    org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:89)
    org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:69)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:423)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:139)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1547)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:673)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:378)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:338)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)
    org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
    com.fanniemae.rbc.rollup.service.RLSchemeMgmtService.getLoanAttributes(RLSchemeMgmtService.java:82)
    com.fanniemae.rbc.rollup.ui.UICache.initialize(UICache.java:42)
    com.fanniemae.rbc.rollup.ui.RollupActionServlet.init(RollupActionServlet.java:22)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Comment: In exceptions, the last root cause is usually telling you what is actually going on.

Answer (score 1):

> java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not
>   establish the connection

This line in the stack trace looks like it's not able to connect to the database. Either the URL is wrong or the server is not running. Check both the server and the URL.

Comment: URL is correct and server is up and running.i have seen welcome page on this url http:\\localhost:8080\.i think the problem is with database.could u help me how to approch this...

Comment: What about the user id and password you used? Make sure you have set up the JDBC datasource correctly.

Comment: First, that's the application server not the database. Databases don't generate web pages.
Try looking up the url format for the database you are using.

Second, connection happens first, then authentication. If the the network adapter can't connect then it's never going to try the password. Also, if it was the password the error would have been an authentication error.

Comment: The url is correct .can u pls let me know how to check the network adapter connection.i'm using jdk1.6,jboss 4.2.3 GA,oracle 11gr2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check several things, check if the username and password are ok, check if the server accept remote connections, check the privileges of user, check if the database port is open (firewall), check the local firewall and check if your host has access to the server (ping ip server)